# Временная активация функции

Tags: javascript

Добры вечер.

У меня есть функция:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function AUTOREFRESH2()
{
$('#ajax').load('checkready.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, ); 
</script>
```

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку эта функция работала 5 секунд?
Потом как пройдет 5сек, то она отключалась бы.

Comment: `clearInterval`  В коде вопроса пропущен второй параметер в вызове `setInterval`.

Comment: А можно кодом написать ответ?

Comment: Что значит "функция работала 5 секунд"? какая функция?

Answer (score 2):

```
function AUTOREFRESH2() {
  $('#ajax').load('checkready.php').fadeIn("slow");
}); 

setTimeout(AUTOREFRESH2, 5000);
```

> Этот метод выполняет код(или функцию), указанный в первом аргументе,
>   асинхронно, с задержкой в delay миллисекунд.
>
> В отличие от метода setInterval, setTimeout выполняет код только один
>   раз.